# Flash Plugin for Firefox on Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, firefox, flash

I have 3 TS on Windows Server 2008. One of the user need to have Flash plug in on her Firefox. She could not install the plugin as she does not have administration access to do that on the TS.

My understanding is the plugin can only be installed as per user. I did try to install the plug in on the server as administrator. However, it is not fixing the situation, as once the user log back in, the Flash is still not working.

Is there any solutions to tackle this issue?

Thank you so much in advance for helping me.

Comment: There's a difference between plug-ins and extensions on Firefox. Plug-ins like Flash install on the PC and are normally available system-wide, Extensions install into the user's Firefox profile and are usually only available per-user.

Comment: @GAThrawn the thing is Internet Explorer has had the Flash Player and working OK. I am thinking as Firefox is using different plug-ins for Flash. I am bit confuse now with the terms of Plug-ins and Extensions, as when I looked at the Firefox Plug_ins of mine, it is listed as Shockwave Flash 10.2.159.1 Plug-ins.

Comment: if you look at the download page linked by Zoredache below, you'll see there's two installers. One installs the ActiveX control for Flash that will only work in IE, the other installs the NSPlugin version that works in all the other main browsers, you have to install that one for Firefox, that installs on the machine at the system level and is available for all users. Shockwave Flash is the right one, that you want. Rule of thumb in Firefox is if it shows in "about:plugins" it's there for all users, if its in Tools -> Add-Ons its for that user only. There are exceptions but they're rare

Comment: @GAThrawn, let me try your advice. Will let you know the result.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186504):

> Use change user /install before installing an application to create .ini files for the application in the Terminal Server system directory. These files are used as master copies for the user-specific .ini files. After installing the application, use change user /execute to revert to normal .ini file mapping.

As an Administrator, download the Flash installer and then in the command prompt window, type:

> change user /install

Run the Flash installer and then launch Firefox and test the Flash plugin. Now type:

> change user /execute

Answer (score 0):

Get the [MSI](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html) and deploy via Group Policy.